# ERROR: Oozie workflow with sqoop action

Tags: sqoop, oozie

I have a problem when I created a workflow in oozie with sqoop action, the return Message Erros: 
`Main class [org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain], exit code [1]`

my workflow.xml is:

```
<workflow-app xmlns='uri:oozie:workflow:0.5' name='sqoop-workflow'>
    <start to='sqoop-load' />

    <action name="sqoop-load">
        <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                    <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
            </configuration>
            <command>import --hbase-create-table --hbase-table <table_name> --column-family <family_name> --hbase-row-key <key_row> --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://<server>:<port>;database=<database>;username=<user>;password=<pass>" --query "SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE \$CONDITIONS AND <column_name> != ''" -m 1</command>
        </sqoop>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="fail" />
    </action>

    <kill name="fail">
        <message>Sqoop export failed, error
            message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>

    <end name='end' />
</workflow-app>
```

and my job.properties:

```
nameNode=hdfs://localhost:8020
jobTracker=localhost:8032
queueName=default
examplesRoot=examples
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.libpath=/user/oozie/share/lib
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/
```

my 'oozie.libpath' contain the mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre7.jar for connection SQL Server and 'oozie.wf.application.path' have my workflow.xml

I run the workflow.xml with the command:

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config job.properties -run
```

OBS: I run everthing in Clodeura VM.